# How to prepopulate a class that inherits combobox

Tags: vb.net

I'm extending the ComboBox class in VB.NET and I'm running into a problem prepopulating the collection.  I try to do so by using Me.Items.Add() calls in the New() sub.  However, once I place the control on a form in the form designer, Visual Studio automatically adds those items to the collection in form designer, then they are added again at runtime.  How can I make them only added once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to check DesignMode property.

in Constructor code you have to add

```
if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) then
    this.Items.Add("test")
endif

if( not DesignMode) then ' not working
    //add your items
endif
```

Comment: I did that, but it's still listing everything twice.

Comment: try this  if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
            {
                this.Items.Add("test");
            }